# Embed command Discord

Tags: discord, discord.py

Wanna embed this code:

```
@bot.command(pass_contex = True)
async def Dragning(ctx, num):
    try:
        arg = random.randint(1, int(num))
    except ValueError:
        return await ctx.channel.send("Endast hela nummer")
    else:
        return await ctx.channel.send(str(arg))
```

Have tried whit all i can find, like:

```
@bot.command(pass_contex = True)
async def Dragning(ctx, num):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Dragning")
    try:
        arg = random.randint(1, int(num))
    except ValueError:
        return await ctx.channel.send("Endast hela nummer")
    else:
        return await ctx.channel.send(str, embed=Embed(arg))
```

And i few other ways, anyone that can give me some pointer?

Comment: Apart from the answer below, you also dont need to add the `pass_context = True` so you can just say `@bot.command()` and it would work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is `ctx.send(embed=Embed(arg))`. What you're *supposed* to do is send the embed instance that you already created earlier, so in your case `ctx.send(embed=embed)`. You're supposed to add the value into the embed instead of creating a new Embed with that value (which doesn't even work).

```
@bot.command()
async def Dragning(ctx, num):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Dragning")
    try:
        arg = random.randint(1, int(num))
        embed.description = arg
    except ValueError:
        return await ctx.send("Endast hela nummer")
    else:
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I added it into the description, as you didn't provide a field title or anything. You can also add this as a field, footer, and more.

More info on what embeds can do (fields, ...) in the [API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed).

Also, you can just use `ctx.send()` instead of `ctx.channel.send()`, and the `pass_context` kwarg [**no longer exists**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=pass_context) so you should remove that from the command decorator. Context is now automatically passed.

Comment: Thanks, now i get that part :)